# Old and New component data using route both are displayed on screen in angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have 3 **Components**:

(1) guessComponent  (2) signupComponent (3) mainComponent

I have write the **selector** of guessComponent in **app.component.html** file.

```
 <a  routerLink="/signup" class="active">Sign up</a>
```

I use route to display other component data on screen, but when i click on any anchor, both **guessComponent** and **signupComponent** data **displayed**

[image]

I want when i click on signup just its data will be displayed.

My **app.module.ts** routing **configuration** is:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent
      }
    ])
  ]
```

Comment: could you add the routing configuration to your question? It's hard to answer with this much informations

Comment: i have added in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  < RooterOutlet > div Allows Angular to know where the views to the roads will be placed. Angular works in SPA (Single Page App) mode. So you need to have an Entry component (main.component) with Only RooterOutlet div. At each call the view will be loaded here.

In your example you added RooterOutlet at the end of a page. So when you call your view, angular loads the page here.

Comment: there is no browserAnimaton module in my app.module.ts

Comment: when user run app login component will be displayed. To display login page i put login-page selector in app.component.html file. Am i doing right/wrong

Comment: No, the best way is to define an empty route :

  { path: ' ', component: LoginComponent },

Comment: I have added default path in app.moudle.ts and in app.component i have added <router-outlet></router-outlet> but it doesnot work